# .htaccess failing with RewriteBase

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have an htaccess file that

1. Takes care of making for example `example.com/fr` behave as `example.com/index.php?lang=fr`
2. Handles the blog:

--

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_rewritten} !=1
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^lang=([a-z]{2})$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /%1/$1? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/js/
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})(?:/([^/]+))?$ $2?lang=$1  [NC,L,QSA,E=rewritten:1]

#If the following part is removed, it works fine
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`RewriteBase` isn't even needed here because that is applicable for relative paths in `.htaccess`.

You should keep these rules in site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+[^?]*\?lang=([^\s&]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%2/%1? [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/js/
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})(?:/([^/]+))?$ $2?lang=$1  [NC,L,QSA]
```

And create `blog/.htaccess` and keep these rules in `blog/.htaccess`:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```